# How to override Google Cloud Project in Firebase in case of Default Service Account? (go admin sdk)

Tags: firebase, go, google-cloud-platform

**Background**

Consider the function [`func NewApp(ctx context.Context, config *Config, opts ...option.ClientOption) (*App, error)`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-go/blob/master/firebase.go#L142) .

Theoretically it should be possible to override the project ID via [the `config` parameter](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-go/blob/master/firebase.go#L156).

However, the problem is that when the [credentials are fetched](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-go/blob/master/firebase.go#L145), the project ID is also determined, and this happens *before* the override via `config` (or via `GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT`/`GCLOUD_PROJECT` env. variables for that matter.)

As a result, the token will be for the "default" project ID, not the overridden one.

**Detailed steps**

Suppose we use the "default service account" as per [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#providing_credentials_to_your_application):

> 2. If the environment variable isn't set, ADC uses the default service account that Compute Engine, Kubernetes Engine, App Engine, and Cloud
>      Functions provide, for applications that run on those services.

So this is what will happen in that case:

[`creds, err := transport.Creds(ctx, o...)`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-go/blob/master/firebase.go#L145)

[`return internal.Creds(ctx, &ds)`](https://code.googlesource.com/google-api-go-client/+/9f3a303b451fc0e0f87fe8987a6b8b90e50369b8/transport/go19.go)

[`cred, err := google.FindDefaultCredentials(ctx, ds.Scopes...)`](https://code.googlesource.com/google-api-go-client/+/9f3a303b451fc0e0f87fe8987a6b8b90e50369b8/internal/creds.go)

[`id, _ := metadata.ProjectID()         // (x) at this point we get the default project ID`](https://go.googlesource.com/oauth2/+/aaccbc9213b0974828f81aaac109d194880e3014/google/default.go)

[`func ProjectID() (string, error) { return defaultClient.ProjectID() }`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/blob/master/compute/metadata/metadata.go#L219)

[`func (c *Client) ProjectID() (string, error) { return projID.get(c) }`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/blob/master/compute/metadata/metadata.go#L357)

[`v, err = cl.Get(c.k)`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/blob/master/compute/metadata/metadata.go#L105)

[`val, _, err := c.getETag(suffix)`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/blob/master/compute/metadata/metadata.go#L334)

[`res, err := c.hc.Do(req)`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/blob/master/compute/metadata/metadata.go#L307)

In short, we get the credentials with the default project ID.

**Question:** Am I missing something, or is there really no way to override the project ID, when using the default service account?

**Addendum:** Maybe the problem is not the `projectID` in the credentials, but getting the bearer token with the default project ID configured there. The base question ("how to override the project") is still valid, though.

Comment: Why do you care about the Project ID? Once you have an Access Token, permissions are based upon the credential and not the project that created the service account. To enable any service account including default service accounts, just add the email address to IAM for the desired project with permissions (roles).